# How to loop a sound

Tags: sound

I have created a sound which I would like to play continuously until stopped, by looping back to the beginning. The sound is represented as list of samples, which can be played by

```
EmitSound[Sound[SampledSoundList[list, rate]]]
```

or

```
ListPlay[list, SampleRate -> rate]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you know the duration, and you should, then: `break = True;
Button["Stop", break = False]
While[break, EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[]]]; Pause[1]]` may be useful. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way of doing a sound loop with a scheduled task. The task is started and stopped with a [`Toggler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Toggler.html) that looks like a play/pause button.

```
sound = Play[(2 t) Sin[2 Pi 2000 t], {t, 0, 1}];
DynamicModule[{state = "pause"},
  Grid[{{
    Toggler[Dynamic @ state,
      {"pause" -> Style["\[RightPointer]", 24], 
       "play" -> Style["\[FilledSmallSquare]", 16]}],
    Dynamic @
      If[state == "play",
        If[ScheduledTasks[] == {}, RunScheduledTask[EmitSound[sound]]]; "playing",
        If[ScheduledTasks[] != {}, RemoveScheduledTask[ScheduledTasks[]]]; "paused"]}}]]
```

It starts off paused, looking like

[image: paused]

Clicking on the right facing triangle starts the sound loop and the `Toggler` changes to black square, so while the sound is playing, the display looks like

[image: playing]

Clicking on square stops the sound loop.

Answer (score 2):

The short code

```
run = True; Button["stop", run = False]
While[True, Print[run]; Pause[1]; If[! run, Break[]]]
```

prints the value of `run` as long as it is `True`.  Clicking the `Button` labeled `stop` sets `run` to `False` and terminates the loop.  Replacing `Print[run]; Pause[1]` by code to play the tones should behave the same.

```
run = True; Button["stop", run = False]
While[True, ListPlay[list, SampleRate -> rate]; If[! run, Break[]]]
```