# Clickable clock making sound

Tags: dynamic, sound

I have a moving clock

```
Dynamic[Refresh[ClockGauge[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

which should be clickable.

Program should make a sound when hand of a clock will touch the point where I clicked before.

I found something like this:

```
EventHandler[
Framed@"Play", {"MouseClicked" :> 
EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 10*^10, "Flute"]],
"MouseExited" :> EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote[SoundVolume -> 0]]}]
```

to make a sound on click.

But I don't know how to get the position of clicked point.

Comment: Which hand? The minute hand?

Comment: the seconds hand

Comment: To get you started, try `{Dynamic[Graphics[Refresh[ClockGauge[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]], 
 Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]}`.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you! Do you have a idea how can I relate to the second hand in code? If[secondHandPosition, ..., ...]

Comment: I think directly accessing the position of the second hand is more troublesome than using `DateValue["Second"]` and converting the point where you clicked into seconds. But you could also use `FullForm@ClockGauge[]` to get the second hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick first draft:

```
DynamicModule[{s = 0, pt = {0, 1}}, 
 Column@{ClickPane[
    Dynamic[Show[Refresh[Graphics[ClockGauge[]], UpdateInterval -> 1],
       Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]], 
      (pt = #; s = 30*(1 + ArcTan[-pt[[2]], -pt[[1]]]/Pi)) &], 
   DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@s, 
    If[DateValue["Second"] == Round[s], 
     EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 0.5, "Flute"]]], 
    UpdateInterval -> 1]}]
```

I'll leave the further refinement to you.

---

In response to a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115073/clickable-clock-making-sound#comment319829_115081).
Using the value of `Clock`:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}, secondHand = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 55}}], clock = 0}, 
 Column@{ClickPane[
    Dynamic[Show[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 60]], 
      Graphics[
       Dynamic[{Rotate[secondHand, (clock = Clock[{0, 59, 1}])*-Pi/30, {0, 0}]}]], 
      Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]], 
    (pt = #; s = 30*(1 + ArcTan[-pt[[2]], -pt[[1]]]/Pi)) &], 
   DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@s, 
    If[clock == Round[s], 
     EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 0.5, "Flute"]]], 
    UpdateInterval -> 1]}]
```

Using the rotated `secondHand`:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}, secondHand = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 55}}], rSH}, 
 Column@
  {ClickPane[
    Dynamic[Show[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 60]], 
      Graphics[
       Dynamic[{rSH = Rotate[secondHand, Clock[{0, 59, 1}]*-Pi/30, {0, 0}]}]], 
      Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]], 
    (pt = #; s = 30*(1 + ArcTan[-pt[[2]], -pt[[1]]]/Pi)) &], 
   DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@s, 
    If[rSH[[2]]*-30/Pi == Round[s], 
     EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 0.5, "Flute"]]], 
    UpdateInterval -> 1]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Works fine!

Comment: @bebrave In your code you are using a duration of `10*^10`. If you like to play a sound until you click something to make it stop, you can use `RunScheduledTask` as shown in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73884/18476).

Comment: I had to change ClockGauge to Circle and rotating Line: `DynamicModule[{s = 0, pt = {0, 1}, secondHand = Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 55}}]}, Column@{ClickPane[Dynamic[Show[Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, 60]], Graphics[Dynamic[{Rotate[secondHand, Clock[{0, 59, 1}]*-Pi/30, {0, 0}]}]], Graphics[{Red, Point[pt]}]]], (pt = #; s = 30*(1 - Sign[pt[[1]]] ArcCos[-pt[[2]]/Sqrt[pt[[1]]^2 + pt[[2]]^2]]/ Pi)) &], DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@s, If[secondHand == Round[s], EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C", 0.5, "Flute"]]], UpdateInterval -> 1]}]`

Comment: Do you have an idea how to read the position of `secondHand`? Unfortunately `secondHand == Round[s]` doesn't work right now.

Comment: @bebrave The `secondHand` never changes. You could use the value of the `Clock` directly or use a rotated `secondHand`.

Comment: @bebrave I added an example for each of these approaches.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my take on that:

```
EventHandler[Dynamic@Refresh[
   If[0 < handAngle - clickAngle < \[Pi]/30, 
    EmitSound[Sound@SoundNote["C"]]]; 
   handAngle = N@Mod[15 - DateValue[Now, "Second"], 60, -30] \[Pi]/30;
    Show[ClockGauge[], Graphics[Point[clickPoint]]], 
   UpdateInterval -> 
    1], {"MouseClicked" :> (clickPoint = MousePosition["Graphics"]; 
    clickAngle = ArcTan @@ clickPoint)}]
```