# Using IF commands in a Dynamic Module

Tags: gui-construction, dialog-window, dynamic

Is there a way to use a functional `If` command in a `DynamicModule`? I have a code which runs a car driving up a street using `Clock` to control its position on the y-axis and the `PlotRange`. I have `MousePosition` controlling the position of the car on the x-axis? I have tried multiple ways to input an If command so that if the car runs into an obstacle, a `CreateDialog` box will pop up saying you have crashed. I cannot figure out how to make this If command cooperate with the dynamic functionality. Any help?

Clarification: Here is a small example of the code that has the heart of the problem. The "car" variable is undefined, but can be easily replaced with just a point, using the x and y variables as its coordinates.

```
finalS = {Slider[Dynamic[v], {10, 500, 10}], Dynamic[v]}; final = 
 DynamicModule[{}, {Graphics[{{White, Thick, 
      Line[{{200, -500}, {200, 175000}}]}, {Yellow, Thick, 
      Dashing[{.1, .05}], Line[{{500, -500}, {500, 175000}}]}, {White,
       Thick, Line[{{800, -500}, {800, 175000}}]}, 
     Inset[Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 4}]}], {x, y}]}, 
    Axes -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-250 + (z Dynamic[v]), 
       750 + (z Dynamic[v])}}, Background -> Black, ImageSize -> 825],
    z = Dynamic[Clock[300]];, x = Dynamic[MousePosition[][[1]]];, 
   y = Dynamic[z*v];}]; 
   finalS final
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible and I used in `If` inside [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115081/18476). To get more specific help from anybody you should add a minimal example to your question.

Comment: Say I wanted to use an if command so that would execute if the car drove off of the road line, how would that be possible?

Comment: Ishnor -- I reformatted your code so that it can be copied. I changed "car" to an orange ellipse. But I do not know what kind of answer you are looking for: what kind of collision with what obstacle?

Answer (score 1):

This will open a dialog notebook created by `CreateDialog` as soon as you "drive" over the left sideline.

```
final = DynamicModule[{dialogQ = False}, 
     {Graphics[{{White, Thick, Line[{{200, -500}, {200, 175000}}]}, 
      {Yellow, Thick, Dashing[{.1, .05}], Line[{{500, -500}, {500, 175000}}]}, 
      {White, Thick, Line[{{800, -500}, {800, 175000}}]}, 
      Inset[Graphics[{Orange, Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 4}]}], {x, y}]}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {-250 + (z Dynamic[v]), 
        750 + (z Dynamic[v])}}, Background -> Black, 
     ImageSize -> 825], z = Dynamic[Clock[300]];, 
    x = Dynamic[MousePosition[][[1]]], y = Dynamic[z*v]; 
    DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[dialogQ, TrackedSymbols :> {dialogQ}], 
     If[Setting@x < 200 && ! dialogQ, dialogQ = True; 
      CreateDialog[{TextCell["You went " Style["OFF ROAD!", Red]], 
        DefaultButton[DialogReturn[dialogQ = False]]}, Modal -> True]], 
     TrackedSymbols :> {x}]}];
```

I just added the part containing the `If` statement at the end of your code leaving the rest unchanged.

Comment: awesome thank you so much. I should be able to do the rest of the If commands based off of this. Much appreciated